# Dark / light modes for SVG (produced by Gnuplot) included in a markdown file

Tags: css, svg, google-chrome-extension, gnuplot, darkmode

I have a SVG file produced with Gnuplot

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"  standalone="no"?>
<svg 
 width="180" height="200"
 viewBox="0 0 180 200"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
<title>Gnuplot</title>
<desc>Produced by GNUPLOT 5.4 patchlevel 1 </desc>

<g id="gnuplot_canvas">

<rect x="0" y="0" width="180" height="200" fill="none"/>
<defs>

    <circle id='gpDot' r='0.5' stroke-width='0.5' stroke='currentColor'/>
    <path id='gpPt0' stroke-width='0.167' stroke='currentColor' d='M-1,0 h2 M0,-1 v2'/>
..
<g fill="none" color="black" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.00" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter">
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

which contains a lot of `'currentColor'` variable. I include the file in a Markdown file using

```markdown
![](gnuplot.svg)
```

and show it using Chrome with [Markdown Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk) extension, which has GitHub and GitHub Dark scheme.

I have tried to include

```css
<style>
/* Light mode */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    body {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        fill: black;
    }
}

/* Dark mode */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    body {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        fill: white;
    }
}
</style>
```

in the SVG file but it does not work as I toggle beetween light and dark modes. I prefer not to use JavaScript since the markdown viewer does not support it.

Is there a way, which just modifies the SVG produced by Gnuplot that will be responsive to toggling light/dark mode from the Chrome extension?